# Displaying MySQL Data in a two-column table

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I have a MySQL table with about 50 records in it. I want each record to be listed as an `<li>`, and I want each column distributed equally...so basically, 25 on one side and 25 on the other.

Here is what I want to output:

```
<li><a href='datasheets/shielded/".$row['Link']."' class='tt'/>".$row['P/N']."<span class='tooltip'><span class='top'></span><span class='middle'>
    <strong>".$row['Description']."</strong><br />
    ".$row['Min L']."".$row['Min L Val']." to ".$row['Max L']."".$row['Max L Value']."<br />
    <strong>DCR(".$row['DCR Val']."):</strong> ".$row['Min DCR']." to ".$row['Max DCR']."<br />
    <strong>Rated DC (".$row['DC Val']."):</strong> ".$row['Min DC']." to ".$row['Max DC']."<br />
    ".$row['Other Info']."</span><span class='bottom'></span></span></a></li>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I usually have 2 divs, in each li one with the class left and one with class right. And have the two floats left and right with a 50% width. Then the li should have a clear:both; style.

Comment: why the mysql tag? It's more simple acting at application level.

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17. I put the MySQL tag on here because I figured it would be appropriate, considering that's where I'm pulling the data from.

Comment: Output each item in a div (or li) element that has `width: 50%; float: left;`. They will automatically show up side by side. If you want to add padding, you'll have to add a div inside the li. Adding padding or marging on the li itself will make it larger than 50%.

Comment: Thank you, GolezTrol! That worked brilliantly :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, do you mean 25 records on the left of the table and another 25 on the right? This case it would be:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
// make sure you connected to your database
$d = mysql_query( "SELECT FROM `mytable` ORDER BY id DESC" )
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($d);
for ($count = 1; $count <= $numRows; $count ++){
$c = mysql_fetch_array($d);
$od = false;
if ($count < 25 && $od == false){

}else{
$od = true;
?>
</td><td>
<?php
}
?>
<li>
<a href='datasheets/shielded/".$c['Link']."' class='tt'/>".$c['P/N']."<span          class='tooltip'><span class='top'></span><span class='middle'>
<strong>".$c['Description']."</strong><br />
".$c['Min L']."".$c['Min L Val']." to ".$c['Max L']."".$c['Max L Value']."<br />
<strong>DCR(".$c['DCR Val']."):</strong> ".$c['Min DCR']." to ".$c['Max DCR']."<br />
<strong>Rated DC (".$c['DC Val']."):</strong> ".$c['Min DC']." to ".$c['Max DC']."<br />
".$c['Other Info']."</span><span class='bottom'></span></span></a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

If this isn't the answer you weren't looking for, please try and explain in a different way :) Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I actually used GolezTrol's method, but what I meant was displaying them in a dynamic table, not necessarily with 25 entries on either side. I basically wanted to take the data from MySQL and put half in the left column and half in the right column.